# MySQL select with categories

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
section
=======
id

cat
===
id
section_id

product
=======
id
cat_id
```

and I would like to select all the products matching a certain section. Is there a way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all data related to the section :

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
INNER JOIN section ON section.id=cat.section_id
WHERE section.id = 5
```

Slightly faster solution which will ignore the section table altogether.

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
WHERE cat.section_id = 5
```

Comment: Might need to add `WHERE section.id = 5` where 5 is whatever the section is you want.

Comment: If you are filtering by section Id and you don't require the section data, adding section table to the query is innecesary. you should use product and cat and filter by cat.section_id.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from product a left join cat b on (b.id=cat_id) left join section using (id);

Answer (score 0):

To select all products from a single section Id:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    product INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
WHERE
    cat.section_id = <section id to filter>
```

Example for section id 4:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    product INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
WHERE
    cat.section_id = 4
```

Also you can search all the items that complains two or more ids, For example searching items with section 1,4 and 7 :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    product INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
WHERE
    cat.section_id in (1,4,7)
```

To select all products with certaing section using "other" section field than section id

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
   product
   INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
   INNER JOIN section ON section.id=cat.section_id
WHERE
    section.<other field> = <the field value>
```

Example with a section field (for example) "name" and searching the value "Section name 1"

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
   product
   INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
   INNER JOIN section ON section.id=cat.section_id
WHERE
    section.name = 'Section name 1'
```

Also is really recommended to replace the "*" and get only the fields that you really require. This helps to fetch only the data that you needed.

For example if you only need the product "id" and a "ficticius" field named "name" from product you should do: (for the first example query)

```
SELECT 
    product.id as productId, product.name as productName
FROM 
    product INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id=product.cat_id
WHERE
    cat.section_id = <section id to filter>
```